# Specifically, how to upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10 (next development version) from the command-line?

Tags: upgrade, updates, 18.04, do-release-upgrade

I am ready to upgrade to the next version of Ubuntu.  I know that Ubuntu 18.10 has not yet been released, but I like to live on the edge.

It also makes me feel good to get massive upgrades of over 100 packages on some days.  This really makes me feel that I am getting my money's worth (even though it is free software and I haven't paid anything for it!).

I therefore would like to upgrade from Ubuntu 18.04 to 18.10 now.

When I run `sudo do-release-upgrade`, it tells me that no further upgrades are available.  Similarly in `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` there are no options for the development release.

Is there a special command to upgrade to the current development release?

Comment: Ok - I have removed the answer here since we already have the same answer on the duplicate.  Since we have a duplicate status, the SE system will now autoredirect to the correct duplicate.

Comment: Why have all the comments been removed?

Comment: This is a different question, I am asking specifically from one version to the next, and that is important because that is what some naive search for.

Comment: @fossfreedom - And oh, my question has been visited more times in the 2.5 years than the question that it is marked as a duplicate of.

Comment: The redirected answer is specifically NOT for command line upgrades!